# How to bind multi IOCP handle to a single file handle to split read / write request?

Tags: c++, windows, file, io, iocp

I want to split read write request to a single file. And I still want to leverage on IOCP to get best performance.
In detail. I want to bind a file handle `F` to two IOCP queue. One for read names `R`, one for write names `W`.
For `R`, I will use it in thread `T1` and work on polling mode.
For `W`, I will use it in thread `T2` and work on wait interrupt mode.
How to do that?

Comment: Maybe I can create two file handles `F1` and `F2` to split read / write request on a single file?

Comment: This impossible and main -absolute senseless.